# Set the path to Python 3 in an IDE on Mac OS X

Tags: python, ide, path, python-3.x

I'm going to write some Python 3.2 scripts in Ninja IDE on Mac OS X. However, I quickly found out that the IDE uses the Python 2.7 interpreter that came with the system by default.

The preferences' currently specified "Python Path" is simply "python". I want to use Python 3.2 all the time, and I guess it's a question of writing or finding the right path in the preferences. In "Terminal", I usually just use a "python3" statement followed a filename, but neither this nor a longer path has been of much help.

I'm sure the answer is dead simple, but my google skills and other technical know-how hasn't given me an answer so far. Any help is much appreciated :-)

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the Preferences-window.
[image: This is how the preferences screen looks]

Comment: In what way was setting the Python executable in the preferences not "much help"?

Comment: When I set it to "python3", I just get "failed to start". I've dug through the filesystem, and I've also tried to find the location of the python 3 interpreter by typing "which python3" in the Terminal. I then tried to use the Python Path "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3", but still I only get the message "Failed to start".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninja IDE is not compatible with python 3 to use python 3 you will have to find another IDE for OSX I recommend using eclipse with the Pydev plugin,
here is a tutorial on how to install pydev and eclipse: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHRRiBHI3to

link to the faq: https://github.com/ninja-ide/ninja-ide/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Usually "/usr/bin/python3" which is a softlink to wherever you installed Python 3.

Since OS X ships with 2.7, you need to download and install Python 3 yourself.

Comment: Then create a softlink to it in /usr/bin, eg: if I installed it to Applications, then "sudo ln -s /Applications/Python3/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3"

Answer (score 0):

http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/

I just followed that link and my system now uses python3.4 in shell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was asking specifically about Ninja IDE. It seems it's not possible at this point in time ;-)